# Create a simple unit tests framework from scratch in Coldfusion

Tags: unit-testing, coldfusion, frameworks, coldfusion-9

I know there are existing tools for testing a ColdFusion application (MXUnit, MockBox), but I'm creating a custom tool, so that it will require less configuration.

When I run a unit test file, it's done *via* a generic 'model' which retrieves all functions from the unit test file. Within each test function, I have to call `assertEquals` -- but these functions are in the model, so I cannot access them.

I tried by passing the model itself to the unit test file so it can call the models functions directly but it doesn't work and it adds logic to the test file, which I don't like.

I can also extend the model in the test file but I will have to call directly the test file, call `super.init(this)` so the model can fetch test functions, etc..

Is there a way to achieve this kind of process? What's the best option?

Comment: Seriously: whatever reason you think you have for not using an existing testing framework you're almost certainly mistaken. So the answer here is "do not do what you're setting out to do", and "the best option" is to use TestBox instead. TestBox is very richly featured, known to already work, and is dead easy to use. Why not just use it?

Comment: I am curious to know if the propensity to reinvent the wheel is more prevalent in the ColdFusion community or if communities surrounding other languages do the same. As Adam said, the best answer is to not reinvent the wheel and use an existing library.

Comment: I know it's re-inventing the wheel like John Whish said but it's also to learn more about how to achieve this kind of work and because I like writing code myself :)
I read a bit about testbox, I think I will use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In answer to your question, it sounds like you want to inject variables / methods into the subject under test. You can do it like so:

```
myInstance["methodName"] = myFunction;
```

You can then call the injected method like so:

```
myInstance.myFunction();
```

Both MXUnit and TestBox use this technique.

Having said that I don't quite understand why you want to re-invent the wheel. TestBox is an excellent, proven testing framework which has a wealth of features which would take you an incredible amount of time to replicate. I'm not quite sure what the configuration issue you have could be - it really doesn't require very much setup. Maybe it might be worth asking how to setup and use TestBox rather than how to build your own testing solution :)

There is a good book (which is available in a free version) which you can read on TestBox here : http://testbox.ortusbooks.com/

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
TestBox looks like the right thing but I want something on which I can have my own CSS style, my own type of display.
You said that TestBox has a wealth of features but maybe I don't need all these features, as I said in the title: simple unit test framework ;)
Anyway, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Then use the bits you want :) Testbox can produce reports in JSON/XML etc so you could use that data to build your own views if you want to be able to style it.

Comment: May I have some more information on what is myinstance, mehtodName and myFunction?
I have to use `cfinvoke` (CF9) because of course, the test functions are called dynamically in the 'model'. Thank you

Comment: Ok, I manage to make it work. But I have another problem, accessing properties within the test component...

Comment: inject a method that reads / sets the property values. Mockbox (bundled with TestBox) has `$property()` and `$getproperty()` methods. http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/MockBox.cfm#.24property()